# cannot import name 'FFProbe' from 'ffprobe'

Tags: python, pydub

**Background:**
I have the following code, which should navigate to the `mp3files` dir on my mac and then convert all `.mp3` files to `.wav` files.
**Code:**

```
import os
from pydub import AudioSegment
from ffprobe import FFProbe

path = "/Users/my_username/Documents/uc_davis/Homework_Repos/classify-spotify/william/mp3files"
os.chdir(path)

audio_files = os.listdir()

for file in audio_files:
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
    if ext == ".mp3":
       mp3_sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(file)
       mp3_sound.export("{0}.wav".format(name), format="wav")
```

**Issue:**
Upon running this code in Jupyter Lab, I get a 
`ImportError: cannot import name 'FFProbe' from 'ffprobe' (/Users/my_username/anaconda3/envs/my_environment_name/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ffprobe/__init__.py)`
**What I've tried:**
I have double-checked that I have the correct dependencies installed and the dir that the ImportError is referencing DOES have the correct files in it.

Does anyone have any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this EXACT issue once, I went to: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/, which contains `ffprobe.py` (which has FFProbe and stuff in it) and `__init__.py` (which has `from ffprobe import FFProbe` in it)

short version: Basically I changed the `print x` statements inside `ffprobe.py` to `print(x)` statements by adding parentheses, and the `from ffprobe import FFProbe` statement to `from .ffprobe import FFProbe`

longer version: I dragged and dropped `ffmpeg.py` in and modified `__init__.py` and gradually modified them to match `ffprobe.py` until I found the problem. I noticed that the ffmpeg file's initialization contained periods so I copied that, and then started getting error messages around the print statements and fixed those too. Here's a pic w/ new on the left, init in middle, and old on the right if it helps at all...[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

I removed `from ffprobe import FFProbe` I re-ran my code, I had no issues. ffproble is not required.