# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'ffprobe' (AudioSegment)

Tags: python, ffmpeg, permission-denied, ffprobe, audiosegment

I am trying to get `AudioSegment` working on my local computer. After resolving some issues, I am stuck on a permission error that I cannot seem to resolve. Let me detail what I have done so far (so that the error is easy to detect):

I `pip` installed both `ffprobe` and `ffmpeg`. But when I `import ffprobe`, it raised `ImportError: cannot import name 'FFProbe'`. Thankfully, was able to fix it following a brilliant post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63912426/cannot-import-name-ffprobe-from-ffprobe). But now when I run `audio = AudioSegment.from_file(audioname)`, it raises the following error: `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'ffprobe'`. Based on one of the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71459878/audiosegment-unable-to-find-ffmepg-and-ffprobe), I manually adjusted the permissions using (which I think is the maximum permission granted to a folder?):

```
import os
import stat
os.chmod('/path/to/ffmpeg', stat.S_IRWXU)
os.chmod('/path/to/ffprobe', stat.S_IRWXU)
```

Just to be 100% sure, I then manually adjusted the permissions for all the files in `ffmpeg` and `ffprobe` folders using `stat.S_IRWXU`, but to no avail (also tried chmod 755). I also confirmed if execution permission was actually granted (using `os.access(my_file, os.X_OK)`) but still get the same error. (Also changed the permission for the `.mp3` file, no luck)

Additional details:

1. Based on a suggestion somewhere, I also added the following options right after importing `AudioSegment`:

```
AudioSegment.converter = "/path/to/ffmpeg"
AudioSegment.ffmpeg = "/path/to/ffmpeg"
AudioSegment.ffprobe = "/path/to/ffprobe"
```

2. There is also a runtime warning (that I don't think has anything to do with the error I get) but mentioning it here for completion:

```
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydub/utils.py:198: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffprobe or avprobe - defaulting to ffprobe, but may not work
  warn("Couldn't find ffprobe or avprobe - defaulting to ffprobe, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Update:

I manually deleted `ffmpeg` and `ffprobe` and then installed `ffmpeg` via `brew install`. It worked!

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/238680